# Passing data from a route to a controller [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to pass a variable from my routes file to the controller specified. Not using parameters as the information is not in the URL. I can't figure out a way to pass it using the below code.

```
Route::get('faqs', [
    'as' => 'thing',
    'uses' => 'Controller@method',
]);
```

I know you can redirect to a controller as well but the error says that the method does not exist and after searching I found that the controller had to be assigned to a route and after that it was still the same error but in a different location.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense from an MVC perspective.  The routes file is just defining routes, it shouldn't be concerned about passing variables to controllers (outside of URL parameters).  If you are working some kind of logic inside that routes file to pass to the controller, that would probably be better off placed inside of some middleware.  I think if you explain the underlying problem or thing you are trying to accomplish which requires parameters in the routes file, we might be able to come up with a better way.

Comment: With GET request you can only pass data as a parameter, otherwise using POTS you can pass any data but using a form or JS. Can you explain what data you want to pass and give more details on what you plan to do this way?

Comment: If you won't use function parameters or input parameters, how will the controller access the data?

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be achieved is by creating custom [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#defining-middleware) by adding your custom fields to the attributes property.

So you would do;

```
$request->attributes->add(['customVariable' => 'myValue']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Route::bind to assign value for specific slug

```
Route::bind('parameter', function($parameter)
{
    return SomeModel::where('name',$parameter)->first();
});

Route::get('faqs/{parameter}', [
    'as' => 'thing',
    'uses' => 'Controller@method',
]);
```

And in your controller set this as a method parameter

```
public function method(SomeModel $model)
{
    dd($model);
}
```